# is it possible to make an ALB forward a request to an unhealthy instance within a Target Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

Here my problem:

I have a Target group containing two EC2 instances. One Instance is healthy, the other is not. ( my health check configurations are especially designed to make one healthy and the other not).

An application Load Balancer will be configured to forward requests to the above mentioned TG.

As known, an ALB only forwards requests to healthy instances within a TG, but we want to see the Http_status code returned from **unhealthy** instances, so I am asking if there is a method to do that.
( wether by making the ALB forward the request to the unhealthy instance or by another mean )
Thank you

Comment: You want the request to be sent to both instances or only the unhealthy one? Why intentionally have it unhealthy if you still want requests to go there?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the request is sent to both or not. Most importantly I want to see the response from the unhealthy instance ( Http Status code ). It was a requirement from a team member. He wants to see what an unhealthy instance gives as response.

Comment: Send the request directly to the instance instead of through the load balancer

Comment: you can enable logs for load balancer to see which http response is taken from health check.

Comment: do the ALB logs really cover the health check responses ? I didn't know that, could you show me a proof of that please ?. I thought it would onlly mirror the requests made to the ALB and their respective responses, but not the health check activities of Target groups !